# Building Orocos Components in ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, orocos, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My system has used rtt_ros_integration in the past to build Orocos Components in a ROS Package in ROS Indigo. We are trying to update our systems to ROS Kinetic. I can't find an rtt_ros_integration like package that would work in ROS Kinetic, is one being developed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252790/building-orocos-components-in-ros-kinetic/) by [jdcarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26475/jdcarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use rtt_ros_integration package with branch 2.9 from [github](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration). This will work like a charm.  follow the instructions as it is. but before that also instal ruby, gems and ruby-dev packages. if u want corba support than when building orocos_package inside underlay_isolate pakage use catkin_make_isolated --install -DCORBA ...

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0